# Como cuidar do status em uma parte do sistema?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Uma dúvida que tenho é de como cuidar do status de uma parte do sistema.

Assim, vou dar um exemplo, tenho uma tabela de pergunta e uma de respostas para essa pergunta.

Nessas tabelas eu tenho campo de data (pergunta:dt_prazo e resposta:dt_resposta)

Preciso saber, quando uma pergunta esta:

- vencida
- em aberto
- respondida

Mas para isso seria até simples, só verificar as datas, se foi ou não respondido e fazer as comparações.

Mas dai que eu entro com o problema:

Pensa que para um determinado cliente, ele não quer o termo "em aberto" e sim "em processo", e por ai vai, querer até determinar uma cor para esse status diferente, isso por cliente.

Será que consegui explicar o meu problema?

Eu pensei em umas tabelas assim

```
PERGUNTA
id
texto
dt_pergunta
cliente_id

RESPOSTA
id
pergunta_id
resposta
dt_resposta

STATUS
id
cliente_id
termo
cor
```

Mas como saber qual status é qual?!

Comment: O termo, a cor, a fonte, o tamanho podem mudar, mas o status em_aberto não.

Comment: Isso nada tem a ver com essas tabelas. Porque o estado é um só. O jeito de apresentar que é diferente. Precisa ter uma tabela diferente que contenha a forma de apresentar para cada cliente.

Comment: Como disse @bigown. Você tem uma tabela que diz que para esse cliente o status em aberto tem a cor X na fonte Y. E você muda esses detalhes entre clientes.

Comment: então @ReginaldoRigo e bigown exatamente isso que estou pensando com a tabela STATUS, mas como relacionar o estado com essa tabela? Tem como?

Comment: Na verdade pelo que entendi essa tabela `STATUS` é exatamente o que precisa, eu achei inicialmente que ela era outra coisa. Bom, não tenho tanta certeza assim, porque a pergunta não está clara quanto a papel de cada tabela. Mas acho que é isso. Como você determina qual é o *status* de uma pergunta? Faça isso e busque esse *sttatus* para esse cliente e use a cor presente ali (ou outra coisa que seja necessário para a apresentação). Essa tabela parece já ser a amarração. O que você precisa é determinar qual é o *status*. Só você pode responder como faz isso. Entendi certo?

Comment: então, essa tabela eu uso sim para essa função de ter o (termo, cor) mas a minha dúvida é, sabemos que uma pergunta caso não tenha sido respondida ainda ela pode esta "Em aberto" ou "Vencida", para isso eu só sei fazendo na programação, dai no caso eu colocaria no próprio código esses termos, cores e tals, mas dai entra o meu problema, como fazer essas comparações e ler na tabela STATUS?

Comment: Eu não sei qual é a dúvida, você descobre em código qual é o estado que a pergunta está, faz uma pesquisa na tabela por esse estado.

Comment: Eu também não entendi a sua pergunta. Vc diz, ali no final: "como saber qual status é qual?". O que é um status? Defina esse termo. Mostre um exemplo do que vai ali no campo status da tabela status. Seria um número inteiro que indique o estado único da pergunta (algo previamente calculado com base nadas datas e tals)? Se sim, esse campo não deveria estar na classe da pergunta? Porque, pelo que eu entendi do seu domínio de problema, uma pergunta pertence somente a um cliente, certo? Ou vários clientes podem ser donos da mesma pergunta, e ela vai ter estado diferente dependendo do cliente?

Comment: @bigown então o que tenho que fazer no caso, é colocar mais um campo na tabela STATUS com um código de estado e dai na programação eu tendo esse código só pegar nessa tabela, é isso?

Comment: Acho que é isso. Não garanto porque não conheço o problema 100%, mas me parece a solução óbvia. Achei até que a coluna `status` era isso.

Comment: @LuizVieira como eu disse, um status pode ser "Vencido", "Em Aberto", "Respondido", mas para cada cliente, pode ter termos diferentes. E o campo "status" alterei para melhor compreensão para "termo". E cada cliente tem suas perguntas, e é uma das coisas que precisaria saber, se coloca tbm um campo a mais na tabela PERGUNTA ou só na programação já basta

Comment: Eu entendi depois de ver a sua alteração. Retirei meu voto pra fechar.

Comment: @bigown entendi, obrigado e vou ver como resolver esse problema que tenho.

Comment: @LuizVieira sim, depois vi por outros cometários que estava gerando dúvida mesmo, e pelo visto acho que vou ter que ter um campo termo e um campo status que dai na programação eu pego por esse campo status e exibo o termo. Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: Eu dei uma resposta. Se eu entendi direito agora, é por aí. Veja lá.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma revisão (afinal, tem coisas pouco claras na pergunta):

- A sua configuração atual de tabelas contém uma tabela chamada `PERGUNTA`, que armazena os dados da pergunta e contém uma chave estrangeira para o cliente que a fez (ou que a detém - o domínio de problema não está claro na pergunta).
- Contém também uma tabela chamada `RESPOSTA`, que contém os dados das várias (0 .. m) respostas possíveis para uma pergunta. Como ela não tem um campo `cliente_id`, está subentendido que todas as respostas pertencem ao cliente da pergunta.
- E contém também uma tabela chamada `STATUS`, que apesar de se chamar assim não tem nada a ver com o estado da pergunta. Pelo contrário, o que ela armazena são preferências dos clientes. Vc chama de `termo` o rótulo do estado da pergunta, e você chama de `cor` a cor em que esse estado será exibido.

Pois bem, para você relacionar a preferência do cliente aos diferentes estados possíveis, você precisa primeiro **definir quais são os estado possíveis**. Isto é, você pode inferir via programação que uma pergunta está "em aberto" porque ela não tem respostas, mas fica impossível relacionar isso nas preferências se essa situação não tiver um identificador que a represente.

O melhor, ao meu ver, seria você ter um campo na tabela `PERGUNTA`, esse sim chamado `status`, por exemplo, que representasse o estado atual da pergunta a partir de uma lista de valores únicos e mutuamente exclusivos (podem ser inteiros 0, 1, 2, 3, ..., etc, desde que cada um represente um único estado). Aí você modela a sua tabela de preferências (que, aliás, eu sugiro que tenha esse nome!). Como você tem mais de um estado, você vai precisar ter um relacionamento n x m das preferências para as preferências de cada estado. Então, é mais ou menos algo do tipo:

```
PERGUNTA
...
id_estado

ESTADOS
id

PREFERENCIAS
id
cliente_id

PREFERENCIAS_ESTADOS
id
id_preferencia
id_estado
termo
cor
```

Comment: Entendi uma boa parte do que passou, só que ainda me resta uma dúvida de como eu faria para saber por exemplo quando uma pergunta estará vencida, teria que rodar uma cron todo dia para saber isso, e dai se estiver vencida mudar o estado dessa pergunta?

Comment: Bom, essa é uma lógica do seu domínio de problema, não? Eu imagino que você tenha alguma regra para definir quando uma pergunta vence, e que isso dependa de tempo. Se for assim, você precisa 1) ter um campo que determine o prazo de vencimento e 2) ter algum processo periódico que faça a verificação. Pode ser um cron, por exemplo. Ou algo agendado diretamente dentro do seu sistema. Pra outros estados **que não dependem de tempo**, você altera na hora. Por exemplo, no momento que alguém der a primeira resposta, você já muda o estado para respondido, por exemplo.